# How do you use ng-file-upload and ngImgCrop?

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload, ng-img-crop

I want to create a file uploader that I can upload a picture to my UI, crop it and then send it to my server. I've been using ngFileUpload to upload files and it has worked well. I added ngImgCrop to my project as instructed and imported the html and css from http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/xxo3sk41/590/ into my project to figure out how to use it.  Everything looks good at first glance but when I select a picture from my hard drive it does not appear in the crop area. Could something be hidden or is something else wrong? Here is the jsfiddle html and css:

```
<style>
    .cropArea {
      background: #E4E4E4;
      overflow: hidden;
      width:500px;
      height:350px;
    }
  </style>

<div>Crop Image and Upload</div>
        <button ngf-select ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*">
            Select Picture</button>
        <div ngf-drop ng-model="picFile" ngf-pattern="image/*"
             class="cropArea">
            <img-crop image="picFile  | ngfDataUrl"                 
            result-image="croppedDataUrl" ng-init="croppedDataUrl=''">
            </img-crop>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{croppedDataUrl}}" />
        </div>
        <button ng-click="upload(croppedDataUrl, picFile.name)">Submit</button>
```

I have code that works just for uploading. The picture appears as expected. I wonder why it is for the one and not the other. This code works for ng-file-upload:

```
<div class="photo-upload-text">Upload your image</div>
<a class="upload-button" ngf-select ng-model="logo" href="#">Choose File&nbsp;</a>
<img ngf-src="logo" ngf-default-src="'/thumb.jpg'" ngf-accept="'image/*'">
```

Finally, I laid out two examples. This one allows me to crop the picture but it does not produce a base64 file without a prefix that can be easily uploaded.  The second one though similar does not put the picture up for cropping.

**Allows for cropping but does not produce an acceptable base64 file**

```
<div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
<div class="cropArea">
  <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
</div>
<div>Cropped Image:</div>
<div>
  <img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" />
</div>
```

**I think this provides a good base64 file but I can't crop it to find out**

```
<div>Crop Image and Upload</div>
<button ngf-select ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*">Select Picture</button>
<div ngf-drop ng-model="picFile" ngf-pattern="image/*"class="cropArea">
    <img-crop image="picFile  | ngfDataUrl" result-image="croppedDataUrl" ng-init="croppedDataUrl=''"></img-crop>
</div>
<div>Cropped Image:</div>
<div>
    <img ng-src="{{croppedDataUrl}}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything looks good at first glance but when I select a picture from
>   my hard drive **it does not appear in the crop area**.

Everything works perfectly when I tried reproducing your issue using your code below.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngImgCrop']).controller('UploadController', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
    .cropArea {
      background: #E4E4E4;
      overflow: hidden;
      width:500px;
      height:350px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-img-crop/0.3.2/ng-img-crop.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

  <div>Crop Image and Upload</div>
<button ngf-select ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*">
  Select Picture</button>
<div ngf-drop ng-model="picFile" ngf-pattern="image/*"
     class="cropArea">
  <img-crop image="picFile  | ngfDataUrl"                 
            result-image="croppedDataUrl" ng-init="croppedDataUrl=''">
  </img-crop>
</div>
<div>
  <img ng-src="{{croppedDataUrl}}" />
</div>
<button ng-click="upload(croppedDataUrl, picFile.name)">Submit</button> 
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/danialfarid-angular-file-upload/12.0.4/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-img-crop/0.3.2/ng-img-crop.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the example of ngImgCrop and ng-file-upload and it did not work for me as is. I needed to add the following code to make it work:

```
    var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngImgCrop']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.upload = function (dataUrl, name) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
            data: {
                file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl, name)
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status 
                + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
            $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        });
    }
}]);
```

this code:

```
                $scope.myImage='';
            $scope.myCroppedImage='';

            var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
                var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (evt) {
                    $scope.$apply(function($scope){
                        $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
```